# (Frapi API) How to get Frapi_Database::getInstance() without class or function(Outside MAMP and FRAPI Environment)?

Tags: php, cron, database-connection, mamp, frapi

I am setting up `cron job` in mac using `crontab command`.

> I am using [MAMP PRO](http://www.mamp.info/en/mamp-pro/) as a local server environment for `FRAPI API`.

But I can not get `Frapi_Database::getInstance()` without using class or function in my simple **PHP Script**...

Actually function for getting database instance is as below :

```
 public function __construct()
 {
     $this->dbLink = Frapi_Database::getInstance();
 }
```

But 
`I want to get database instance without using this method from Library,not from Action`. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also had same problem.Include this file into your Cron file:

> > /src/frapi/library/Frapi/AllFiles.php from Frapi API.

It has All necessary file like Libraries,database,adaptor files,etc.

Also If you getwarning like "PHP Notice: Undefined index HTTP_HOST" in internal.php file then replace

> > $_SERVER with getenv

You will get rid out of this.

Comment: Thank you. I am looking for this answer only.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it directly by invoking the static method

```
$connection = Frapi_Database::getInstance();
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply..But i used same way as yours..So i got error like this in php_error log. PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Frapi_Database' not found in this file..While running this file from crontab -l command.

Comment: @DevZero : I can get database instance while running from Frapi..But outside Frapi (i.e. From command line or using crontab(Cron job)) i can not get database instance..Why?

Comment: you need to include the "library/Frapi/Database.php" in your script

Comment: @DevZero : I included Database.php.But I got error in Database.php that "Fatal error: Class 'Frapi_Exception' not found".Thank you for your reply.

Comment: I read about Frapi and it said its a REST Framework. And the code looked like its been setup for WebAccess. i didn't see any initializer script. So you may have to include all the required files manually. For this error i believe you need `library/Frapi/Exception.php`

Comment: @DevZero : Ok,I will try tomorrow and get back to you.

Comment: @DevZero : I incuded all necessary files but I got error as : Undefined index: HTTP_HOST in /src/frapi/library/Frapi/Internal.php on line 310 ..Can you please give solution about this ? Thank you.

Comment: @DevZero : I put my best efforts to find solution to resolve unidentified index : HTTP_HOST by searching and including files. But i can not find any solutions.Thank you for your answers..Can you please tell answer of this? It will help me a lot.

Comment: well thats more of a warning not an error. did it prevent the script from running?

Comment: @DevZero : yes it says `"PHP Notice: Undefined index: HTTP_HOST"`,Is it warning or error ?

Comment: more of a Notice not even a warning

Comment: @DevZero : Ok,Thank you..I reached at this error although i imported all the files under 'Cache/ and Cache/Adapter folder'. `PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Frapi_Cache_Adapter_Frapi_cache_adapter does not exist`.Your help will be appreciated.

Comment: you also need `Cache/Adapter/Frapi`

Comment: @DevZero : But there is no folder named as `Frapi` under `/src/frapi/library/Frapi/Cache/Adapter`. Thanks.

Comment: @DevZero : There is no folder called `Cache/Adapter/Frapi`.Thank you.

Comment: @DevZero  Ok,Thanks for your help....If you have any other solutions for this question then please tell me...